# Jquery/JavaScript: How to limit a droppable box to accepting only one drag item, with replacement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

So, I've created drag/drop boxes where the draggable items originate in a word bank box, and can be placed in a number of other boxes, including being placed back into the word bank box. But, I'm not sure how to do a couple things....

1) How to limit the draggable items accepted per box to 1 item (obviously excluding the word bank). Right now, the drop boxes accept unlimited items from the word bank.

2) If the user attempts to drag a second item into a single drop box, the old item will revert back to the word bank, and the new item will take its place.

Here is my HTML code:

```
    //This is the original word bank box
    <ul id="items1" class="items list-inline dropBox wordBox">
        <li class="list-inline-item g">Item 1-1</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item g">Item 1-2</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item o">Item 1-3</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item o">Item 1-4</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item g">Item 1-5</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item o">Item 1-6</li>    
    </ul>

    //These are two drop/target boxes
    <div id="items2" class="items dropBox targetBoxes"></div>
    <div id="items3" class="items dropBox targetBoxes"></div>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$("#items1,#items2,#items3").sortable({
    connectWith: ".items,#items2,#items3",
    start: function (event, ui) {
        ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
    }
 });
 $("#items1,#items2,#items3").disableSelection();
```

Thank you, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Not sure why you are using sortable versus droppable. Basically, in your `stop` or `drop` function, you'd want to see if the item contains an item and either accepts the dragged item or not.

Comment: [Limit .droppable() to only one item?](//stackoverflow.com/q/19577597)